# Blocked (disabled) email body field in CRM 2013

Tags: email, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

In standard situation when you would like to create an Email through CRM 2013 user interface, you fill sender, recipient, subject and body of email and send it.

But in one specific situation, the body (description) field can be disabled and you are not able to insert any text inside.

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the problem is the setting called **Use secure frames to restrict email message content**. So if you have the problem with the body field, go to the **Settings->Administration->System Settings->Email** tab. Find section **Set Email form options** and set **Use secure frames to restrict email message content** to No. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

We checked this solution, we have the same issue in CRM 2016 8.0 but for us, this setting is already set to "No" and the body is disabled until we save the record.